# Multiple Paths in a Text Game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

https://github.com/addrum/TextGame

So I have this game. What I have achieved so far is that if the user inputs a correct response it returns the next message for them to then figure out what to do from an array. What I need to achieve now is that the program returns a different message depending on what their input is. i.e go left, you reach a door, go right, you pick up a key. I am so confused about how to do this. I thought about grouping messages together at a particular point. So you reach crossroads - and the outputs for go left, go right and go forward are in an array together but then I don't know how to get the program to get the next group of messages. I also had the idea of making the correct input have the index of [0] so that I can then return the current group of messages index of [0] to match that up but this also confused me. If I can make it any clear just ask because I have no easy way of explaining this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There was a related question here somewhere, the idea was to use a tree with decisions as nodes..I can't find it D:

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in writing a text adventure game ("Interactive Fiction" or "IF"), you should consider some of the many tools designed for that.

- Compilers for making text adventures with a traditional lineage can be found off of the [IFWiki](http://www.ifwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page). For example, here's the Parchment interpreter running [Spider and Web](http://iplayif.com/?story=http://mirror.ifarchive.org/if-archive/games/zcode/Tangle.z5) (one of my favorites).  The wiki also has a lot of writing about how to write fun IF.
- [Choice of Games](http://www.choiceofgames.com/) is a company that makes cross-platform IF, mostly targeting mobile devices.  They have their own scripting language for writing IF and if you wanted to sell your game they offer to manage that, too.
- [Twine](http://www.gimcrackd.com/etc/src/) is an IDE for building web-based IF.  It looks easy to write, though I haven't tried it myself.

If this is just a sort of teach-yourself-Java project, then I recommend the following approach:

```
/**
  * Represents one location or one state in the game.
  */
public class DecisionTreeNode {
    /** Text that gets printed when the user lands on this node */
    private final String nodeText;

    /** Maps text that the user can enter to the node that they reach by typing that text */
    private final Map<String,DecisionTreeNode> choices;
}
```

If you fill out that stub, you'll be able to write a very simple subset of IF.  Here's an example of some nodes you might have (using the example game in your question):

- **Start**

  - nodeText: "You are in a corridor that branches left and right"
  - choices:

    1. "left" -> **Door_no_key**
    2. "right" -> **Dead_end_no_key**
- **Door_no_key**

  - nodeText: "there is a door here, but you don't have the key"
  - choices:

    1. "right" -> **Start**
- **Dead_end_no_key**

  - nodeText: "This is a dead end. There is a key here!"
  - choices:

    1. "get key" -> **Dead_end_key**
    2. "left" -> **Start**
- **Dead_end_key**

  - nodeText: "This is a dead end. You are carrying a key."
  - choices:

    1. "left" -> **Start_key**

And so on.  You can see that tracking the player's state makes the game design get out of hand pretty quickly, which is why I recommend IF tools for a serious IF game.  But this could be a nice way to teach yourself about pointers in programming.